# Removing avaliable languages from Localization

Tags: localisation, i18n

[image: How to remove language from Available Languages]

I have added some 5 to 6 languages, I want to remove few of them how can it be done.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it right now using UI. It's a known limitation. cf. https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-10006

It's not a high priority bug right now (not scheduled for a fix).